# Drawing sin function with R and positioning them on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 0:10, y = 0:10)
curve <- tibble( z_1 = seq(0, 20, length.out = 1500),x_1 = sin(z_1),
                z_2 = sin(x_1)+2, z_3 = sin(x_1)+5)

base <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_blank()
base + geom_path(data = curve, aes(x = x_1,y = z_1), color  ='red')+
  geom_path(data = curve, aes(x = x_1+1,y = z_1), color  ='red')+
  geom_path(data = curve, aes(x = x_1+2,y = z_1), color  ='red')+
  geom_path(data = curve, aes(x = x_1+3,y = z_1), color  ='red')
```

I want the output to be something like this. But I would like to have the curves produced by `geom_path` in `x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, x = 4.`

How can I do this? Should I change de data.frame?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "curves in x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, x = 4, x = 5". Can you give a mathematical expression for what you want?

Comment: Do you mean you want the curves to be offset/translated by this amount on the x-axis?

Comment: No, I can't see this as your code doesn't execute: you are using `df` which is not a defined variable, and neither are `x`, and `y` which you use in `aes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# For each different x-offset from 1-5
# Make a new tibble with a constant y value, and sin x value
# These get automatically merged together because of `map_dfr`
curve <- map_dfr(1:5, function(offset){
    tibble(
        y = seq(0, 20, length.out = 1500),
        x = sin(y) + offset,
        offset = offset
    ) 
})

# The only trick here is that we use group=offset to "restart" the 
# function plot for each of the tibbles with different offsets created above
ggplot(curve, aes(x=x, y=y, group=offset)) +
    geom_path(color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your time and patience to understand me.